# superuser authenticate in class based view

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I am working on blog project in which I added an add post which add post now I want only the superuser can add post and that page is visible only to superuser.

**1st Method**
**Views.py**

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'MainSite/add_post.html'
    fields = '__all__'
```

this is my current view I am able to achieve authenticate for superuser using 2nd method 

**2nd Method**

```
class AddPostView(View):
    def get(self,request):
        if request.user.is_superuser == True:
            return render(...)
        else:
            pass
```

How can I achieve the same result using 1st method.I tried using LoginRequiredMixin but nothing is happening . I just import LoginRequiredMixin and use it like this .

```
class Addpost(CreateView,LoginRequiredMixin):
    ...
```

Thanks in advance and advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a [**`UserPassesTestMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class AddPostView(UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    # …
    
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
    
    # …
```

You can encapsulate this in a mixin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class AdminRequiredMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
```

and then use this mixin:

```
class AddPostView(AdminRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # …
    
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
    
    # …
```

Mixins should be put before the actual view in the inheritance hierarchy: otherwise these appear after the view in the *method resolution order (MRO)*, and thus likely will not override the behavior (correctly).

Comment: Thanks this worked but how can I redirect to diffrent page I want to redirect to homepage if user is not superuser currently its showing 403

Comment: @Roshan: you can override the `def handle_no_permission` method, and `return redirect('name-of-some-view')` there. But redirecting to the login URL.

Comment: @WillamVanOnsem Thanks got it and which method for  writing class based view is more efficient method 1 or method 2.(sorry for off topic question)

Comment: @Roshan: it will not matter (or only a fraction of a millisecond), the second one is better if you want to apply the mixin to several views. If you for example want to do this in two, three or more views, you implement the mixin once effectively, and then mix it in the other views and thus prevent rewriting the same logic again.

Answer (score 2):

```
class AddPostView(CreateView,LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'MainSite/add_post.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_anonymous:
           return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(), self.get_login_url(), self.get_redirect_field_name())
        elif request.user.is_superuser:
            return render(.....)
        else
            return super(AddPostView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method_decorator and user_passes_test to achieve this

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

class AddPostView(View):
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser))
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```